# How to exclude specific file from inside lib/ folder from eager_loading in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, eager-loading

In my rails application inside lib/ folder I have many files I need to exclude one file from that lib folder to become `eager_loading` and  remaining file should go `eager_loading`.

How can I achieve this?

1. `config.eager_load_paths += %W[#{config.root}/lib/]`

   In point 1, load all files from lib folder,
2. `config.eager_load_paths -= %W[#{config.root}/lib/iq_analytics.rb]`
   `config.eager_load = true`

   In point 2, I have changed this to exclude `iq_analytics.rb` this file from loading `eager_load`, but this line exclude all files from lib/ folder?

Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

### Rails >= 7.1

You can use [config.autoload_lib(ignore:)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-lib-ignore)

```rb
# config/application.rb

config.autoload_lib(ignore: %w(iq_analytics.rb))
```

### Rails < 7.1 and zeitwerk enabled

```rb
# config/application.rb

lib_dir = Rails.root.join('lib')

config.autoload_paths << lib_dir.to_s
config.eager_load_paths << lib_dir.to_s

Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(lib_dir.join('iq_analytics.rb').to_s)
```

Comment: my rails version is "5.1.3" is any other way to do this with rails  version 5.1.3. ?

Comment: The way you've described should work on rails 5.1.3. Are you sure that's excluding all files from `lib/` folder? Can you make sure `config.eager_load = true` is in `config/environments/development.rb` and test again?

Comment: but i am getting error like: " undefined method `autoloaders' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)" for "Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(lib_dir.join('iq_analytics.rb').to_s)" this line